Bing Search Engine Indexing
Have anyone encountered with the problem and fixed the issue where Bing search engine shows wrong Website name in the header of the search result?
How to fix this issue?
Google Chrome shows it right, but Bing shows it wrong. Does it mean Bing is not indexing web pages right?
